# Manejo de estados de un div padre y div hijo

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo una pregunta que creo es bastante simple pero no le encuentro solución.
Tengo el siguiente código en React-JS y quería saber si es posible que al presionar el botón 1 solo cambie el valor del hijo, y al presionar el botón 2 solo cambie el valor de su hijo, y no que al apretar cualquiera de los 2, ambos hijos cambien

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import './App.css';

function App() {

  const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = () => setClick(!click);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="father" onClick={handleClick}>Button 1/
        <span className="child">{click ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}</span>
      </div>
      <br></br>
      <div className="father" onClick={handleClick}>Button 2/
        <span className="child">{click ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}</span>
      </div>
      
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Algo muy simple que se podría hacer con JQuery al presionar el botón

```
$('div').click(function(){
  $(this).children()...
});
```

Comment: para eso puedes cambiar tu `handleClick` para recibir un parámetro y de esa manera también indicar un tipo de condición diferente para mostrarlo en cada hijo.

Comment: ¿Algún ejemplo de como hacerlo por favor?

Comment: Puedes revisar mi respuesta, es un ejemplo sencillo de como lo puedes hacer, hay mas formas dependiendo de la situación o función especifica a realizar

Answer (score 0):

Esto se puede realizar de diferentes maneras, una forma rápida puede ser con valor numérico para los botones.

Primero cambiamos un poco tu `handleClick` y el valor inicial de `useState`

```
const [click, setClick] = useState(0);
const handleClick = b => setClick(b);
```

lo siguiente es cambiar un poco la validación de **ON/OFF**

```
click === 1
```

Quedando de la siguiente manera

```
<div className="father" onClick={() => handleClick(1)}>Button 1/
    <span className="child">{click === 1 ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}</span>
</div>
<br></br>
<div className="father" onClick={() => handleClick(2)}>Button 2/
    <span className="child">{click === 2 ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}</span>
</div>
```